# Organising dataframe with pandas and pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to modified my dataframe using melt and table pivot.

I have this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pays': {0: 'France', 1: 'France', 2: 'France'},
                   'Indicateur': {0: 'Internet', 1: 'Pop', 2: 'Eco'},
                   '1990': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
                   '1995': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9}})
df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIEJK.png)

I gather columns date into rows with melt :

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars =['Pays','Indicateur'], value_vars =['1990','1995'],
              var_name ='Years', value_name ='valeur')
df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz18g.png)

I spread 'Indicateur' rows into columns :

```
df2 = df.pivot(columns='Indicateur',values='valeur')
df2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxYCL.png)

I would like this result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou7Wh.png)

You know how to do it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is not necessary defined years in `value_vars` in [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), if need all of them:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars =['Pays','Indicateur'], var_name ='Years', value_name ='valeur')
```

Also is necessary defined `index` parameter in [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then remove `column name` by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df2 = (df.pivot(index=['Pays', 'Years'], columns='Indicateur',values='valeur')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(columns=None))
print(df2)
     Pays Years  Eco  Internet  Pop
0  France  1990    3         1    2
1  France  1995    9         7    8
```

EDIT: If need same format like melted DataFrame:

```
df1 = df[['Pays','Years']].join(df.set_index('Indicateur', append=True)['valeur'].unstack())

#or using your solution
df1 = df[['Pays','Years']].join(df.pivot(columns='Indicateur',values='valeur'))
print(df1)
     Pays Years  Eco  Internet  Pop
0  France  1990  NaN       1.0  NaN
1  France  1990  NaN       NaN  2.0
2  France  1990  3.0       NaN  NaN
3  France  1995  NaN       7.0  NaN
4  France  1995  NaN       NaN  8.0
5  France  1995  9.0       NaN  NaN
```

Comment: i want to keep all column in one lign, easier to manipulate for me

Comment: @Giordano - answer was edited. I think `df2` is simplier like `df1`, but it depends what need.